# How to detect client network disconnection?

Tags: spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I've implemented a SSE service by using Spring Webflux and Kafka.

```
client <-- microservice (spring webflux) <-- kafka
```

Above flow is working fine as I'm able to read the SSE stream continuously. Whenever client manually disconnect the request, my microservice will auto cancel the subscription.

However, if the client has some network connection (let say client disable internet network), the webflux is not able to detect the broken connection. It will keep sending the data to a subscription that no longer has a client connected.

In this case, does anyone able to advise on how to detect a network disconnected webflux client?